# Excel - restructuring duplicated rows

Tags: excel

please see below for an example. What I have is on the left, what I want is on the right. Is there any easy way of going about this in excel?

[image]

Comment: What is the length if you what you have? how many distinct IDs? what is the max amount of date per ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this macro handy for that purpose. You can tweak it as required:

```
Sub ConsolidateRows_MultipleCells()
'takes rows and consolidate one or many cells, based on one or many cells matching with above or below rows.

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim colMatch As Variant, colConcat As Variant, lColDest As Long

'**********PARAMETERS TO UPDATE****************
Const strMatch As String = "A"    'columns that need to match for consolidation, separated by commas
Const strConcat As String = "B"     'columns that need consolidating, separated by commas
Const lDest As Long = 2     'starting column for the consolidated items
'*************END PARAMETERS*******************

application.ScreenUpdating = False 'disable ScreenUpdating to avoid screen flashes

colMatch = Split(strMatch, ",")
colConcat = Split(strConcat, ",")

Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Cells(1, colMatch(0)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
                    False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2 _
                    :=xlSortNormal


lastRow = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

lColDest = lDest

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1 'loop from last Row to one

    For j = 0 To UBound(colMatch)
        If Cells(i, colMatch(j)) <> Cells(i - 1, colMatch(j)) Then
            lColDest = lDest
            GoTo nxti
        End If
    Next

    For j = 0 To UBound(colConcat)
        range(Cells(i, strConcat), Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight)).Copy Cells(i - 1, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1)
        lColDest = lColDest + 1
    Next

    Rows(i).Delete

nxti:
Next

application.ScreenUpdating = True 'reenable ScreenUpdating
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the macro! I'm going to use this as an opportunity to actual pick apart VBA code.